# Material UI TextField Label Positioned Incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I'm working with Material UI to create the UI for the web application I'm designing. After placing some `TextFields` within a `Grid` using theme spacing, I'm having troubles with the inner text of the the `TextField` no longer being centered within its container. As soon as I remove the theme spacing from the style applied to the `TextField`, there's no problem anymore.

Here's a codesandbox that showcases the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-sound-vjsm4?file=/src/App.js

Does anyone know how to recenter the text within its `TextField`? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show more detail about what you want to do with ```TextField```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Moving the textInput class to Grid instead of TextField.

```
<Grid item xs={6} className={classes.textInput}>
  <TextField
    id="project-client"
    label="Client"
    variant="outlined"
  />
</Grid>
```

If you inspect and see the HTML, it seems that Material-UI doesn't apply that class to the label but only to the input. Moving the class at grid level should apply it to the entire container (label and input)